# Помогите с позиционированием

Tags: css3, html5, позиционирование, opacity, прозрачность

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста с необычной задачкой, уже долго голову ломаю над ней.
На задней фоне есть картинка, она обязательно должна быть картинкой, и обязательно должны быть адаптивной.
Задача - на заголовке сделать линию, которая будет тянутся в зависимости от длины заголовка, тоесть должен быть и отступ от заголовка любого, и снизу фиксированный.

[макет](http://joxi.ru/VrwWLOkT7kN9Yr)

[image: макет]

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.name {
    width: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    word-break: break-all;
}
.name:before {
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: calc(100% + 30px);
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -1000px;
    position: absolute;
}

.tags {
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 35px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="image"><img src="img/pic.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="name">title</div>
  <ul class="tags">
    <li><a href="#">tag 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tag 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tag 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tag 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tag 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Допили сниппет до работающего. А вообще, не очень понятно, что требуется и в чём именно проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заголовок сделал редактируемым для наглядности

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.name {
    width: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    height: calc(100% - 20px - 50px);
    /*где 20px - отступ сверху, а 50px - снизу*/
    color: #fff;
    display:flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items:center;    
}
.name:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    flex: 1 1 auto;/*растягиваем линию*/
    border-left:1px solid;
}
.title{
  width:100%;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  flex:0 0 auto;/*не даем сжиматься заголовку*/
}


.tags {
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 35px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="image"><img src="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300" alt=""></div>
  <div class="name">
    <div class="title" contenteditable>Nicolas</div>
  </div>
  <ul class="tags">
    <li><a href="#">tag 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tag 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tag 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tag 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tag 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, это какраз то, что нужно!)